# How can I pass command output as first argument to next command

Tags: command-line, bash, xargs

I am using Virtualenv in Python, and I have to execute the pip command with sudo because of windows filesystem... executing `sudo pip` executes the pip outside virtualenv ... so im directly executing the pip file of virtualenv....
I get it by doing

```
(venv) which pip
/mnt/c/twit/venv/bin/pip
```

So I would like to do

```
which pip | sudo *first_command_output_goes_here* install requests
```

I read about `xargs` but i couldn't pass first command output as first argument ...

How can I do this?

Comment: @user535733 Exactly

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions:

- Run `sudo /mnt/c/twit/venv/bin/pip install requests` directly
- Run `sudo $(which pip) install requests`

Comment: I'm not looking for option 1, the second option didn't work as sudo invokes the pip that is outside virtualenv

Comment: Is the virtualenv activated when you run the sudo command?  It works for me:

$ virtualenv test
$ source test/bin/activate
(test) $ sudo $(which pip) debug
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/test/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>

Apparently there's a bug with pip in Ubuntu/Debian but you can see it's executing the right pip.